# CSS transform without affecting child elements?

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I am trying to have a card element move up on hover and then back down when it is no longer hovered. I am currently achieving this by using `transform` and `translate` in CSS. However, I have noticed that this can affect the children elements as well as the element that I want this animation affected by. Here is the HTML and CSS for the card that I have at the moment:

```css
.server :hover {
  -moz-transform: translate(0, -2px);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, -2px);
  -o-transform: translate(0, -2px);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -2px);
  transform: translate(0, -2px);
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="server">
  <div class="card m-2 p-1 text-center">
    <p>Child element</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've used a compound selector when what you probably want is a chain selector. Just add the `:hover` pseudo selector, without a space, directly to the element you want to affect.

```css
.card {
  /* transitions are needed when hover state ends, so set up rules here */
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  transition-property: transform;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
.card:hover { /* note: no space */
  transform: translate(0, -2px);
}
```

```html
<div class="server">
  <div class="card m-2 p-1 text-center">
    <p>Child element</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's a much cleaner answer, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Since children elements would always move with their parent element (same applies to `opacity`), you can set the opposite transform on all children.

I added a red background on the `card` and set `> *` all children to have the opposite transform.

```css
.server :hover {
  -moz-transform: translate(0, -2px);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, -2px);
  -o-transform: translate(0, -2px);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -2px);
  transform: translate(0, -2px);
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.server :hover > * {
  transform: translate(0, 2px);
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.card {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="server">
  <div class="card m-2 p-1 text-center">
    <p>Child element</p>
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="card m-2 p-1 text-center">
    <p>Child element</p>
    <p>Child element</p>
    <p>Child element</p>
    <p>Child element</p>
    <p>Child element</p>
    <p>Child element</p>
  </div>
  
  
</div>
```

Since I'm not sure what your `card` element is actually showing, you could also use a pseudo `::before` or `::after` and assign the transform to that:

```css
.server :hover::after {
  transform: translate(0, -2px);
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.card::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.card>* {
  z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<div class="server">
  <div class="card m-2 p-1 text-center">
    <p>Child element</p>
    <p>Child element</p>
    <p>Child element</p>
    <p>Child element</p>
    <p>Child element</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As much as this is likely to work, the solution offered by Mech seems much more elegant and clean. Sorry!

Comment: Don't be sorry! These solutions still work, but Mech's `:not` is also an appropriate solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify by using `:not`

```css
.server :hover :not(p) {
  -moz-transform: translate(0, -2px);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, -2px);
  -o-transform: translate(0, -2px);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -2px);
  transform: translate(0, -2px);
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="server">
  <div class="card m-2 p-1 text-center">
    <p>Child element</p>
    <div>Child element</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I should have specified that the HTML I used in my question was example, and the code inside the card is more complex. If there are multiple elements, do I just need to add the elements with a comma? `e.g. (p, div, img)` @Mech

Comment: You got it. `:not(p, div, img)`

Comment: You could go even more generic and do a wildcard `:not(*)` Also, please update your answer with all the comment you posted - makes it easier for future visitors - so they don't have to look through comments for the final answer.